# Time, Identity, & memory

Tags: inspiration, school

I have to take pictures for my film class. The assignment about 3 aspects :

- time
- identity
- memory

For a time I was thinking of taking pictures :

- of a small child with the skyline of my town
- of a police officer next to his car
- of a statue of a man

I wanted some expert opinion and guidance, anything will help.

Comment: I edited your question, I hope it is now clearer.

Comment: As this is homework, I recommend anyone considering an answer to read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions - it is code-oriented but the advice holds true across the stackexchange network.  As it stands this question doesn't demonstrate any attempt to find a solution.  I've not voted to close it yet, but we need a more specific question if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for inspiration.

Finding inspiration is a subject which has already been treated in this forum. Have a look at :

- [Where do you find the inspiration for your photographs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/where-do-you-find-the-inspiration-for-your-photographs)
- [How does one develop good photographic vision and style?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-does-one-develop-good-photographic-vision-and-style)
- [How do you develop 'creative taste' in order to take a good photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48464/how-do-you-develop-creative-taste-in-order-to-take-a-good-photo)
- [Is it bad to mimic other photographers to compensate the lack of one's creative skills?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48663/is-it-bad-to-mimic-other-photographers-to-compensate-the-lack-of-ones-creative)
- [What makes a photo a good photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2296/what-makes-a-photo-a-good-photo)
- [What is your favourite photographic inspiration?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/what-is-your-favourite-photographic-inspiration)
- [Which photographer do you find inspirational?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/which-photographer-do-you-find-inspirational)
- [What are good photography projects?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/978/what-are-good-photography-projects)
- [Can anyone suggest books/resources on the artistic side of photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4804/can-anyone-suggest-books-resources-on-the-artistic-side-of-photography)

Your assignment's purpose is probably to develop your creative skills and find inspiration : Which sentiment do you want to create? Why subject "A" and not subject "B"? What kind of focal length using? For which purpose? Why this composition? and so on...

How one treats a subject such as "the time" is mostly opinion-based. As opinion-based question have very little utility for the rest of the world, they are out of topic on this website (have a tour : https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour).

As it is, your question will probably be closed and declared "off-topic".